# Is there a way to reset session variables when user clicks the browser's back button?

Tags: meteor

I'm having this problem in my app that after a Session variable is created on meteor and the user is brought to a new page in Meteor via Iron Router, as soon as the user clicks the browser's back button, the session is not reset (this is remedies by refreshing the page).

Let's say the user wants different options after pressing the back button, it won't work as it's supposed to because the session variable before clicking the back button are still active and not reset.

Is there a way to automatically reset these session variables when a user uses the browser's back button without having to refresh the page entirely?

Comment: It seems like you'd want to use a reactive-var for your user options instead.  Is that an option?

Comment: It's always an option...but I would have to make some changes with my code.

Comment: How about resetting the session variables on iron routers onAfterAction?

Comment: That's a genius idea! Set session variables to false in Iron Router's onAfterAction! Why didn't I think of this earlier lol? You can reply to my post with a post so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset your session variables using IronRouter's onAfterAction:

http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-3/